# How to set API endpoint for the IBM Cloud / Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have downloaded and installed the Cloud Foundry CLI tool "cf". However, I am not able to login because I could not set the API endpoint.

What is the API endpoint that I should provide? Where can I find the related information?

Comment: https://developer.ibm.com/courses/wp-content/uploads/sites/83/2016/08/CDC1-CFCLI-Lab.pdf

Comment: dead link above

Answer (score 21):

If you are using **US South Region**:

use these commands:

```
cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net
cf login -u bluemix_id -o myorg
```

If you are using **United Kingdom region**:

use these commands:

```
cf api https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net
cf login -u bluemix_id -o myorg
```

**for Sydney region**

```
cf api https://api.au-syd.bluemix.net
cf login -u bluemix_id -o myorg
```

**for Germany region**

```
cf api https://api.eu-de.bluemix.net
cf login -u bluemix_id -o myorg
```

you can know which region, org and space is currently set typing:

```
cf target
```

If you are using the 'bluemix' plugin you can use the below command

example: 
`bx api <apiLink>` and `bx target`

Answer (score 16):

For future users who may stumble across this question using the [IBM Cloud CLI](http://clis.ng.bluemix.net/ui/home.html), the commands to set the API Endpoint are very similar:

**US South**

```
ibmcloud api https://api.ng.bluemix.net
```

**US East**

```
ibmcloud api https://api.us-east.bluemix.net
```

**United Kingdom**

```
ibmcloud api https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net
```

**Germany**

```
ibmcloud api https://api.eu-de.bluemix.net
```

**Sydney**

```
ibmcloud api https://api.au-syd.bluemix.net
```

---

After setting the API Endpoint, you can login:

```
ibmcloud login
```

---

Official docs here:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/ibmcloud/bx_cli.html#bluemix_cli

Comment: Note that it is very important *not* to include a trailing slash on these endpoints. If you do, certain commands, such as `bx login`, will fail.

Answer (score 15):

The endpoint depends on the Bluemix region/data center, this one is for the default in North America/Dallas ("US South"):

```
cf login -a https://api.ng.bluemix.net
```

Instead of "ng" you could also have "eu-gb" for London or "au-syd" for Sydney. The [regions for Bluemix Public are documented here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/overview/whatisbluemix.html#ov_intro_reg). If you are on Bluemix Dedicated or Bluemix Local you would need to ask your administrator for the correct name of the API endpoint.

For Bluemix Public:

```
cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net
cf api https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net
cf api https://api.eu-de.bluemix.net
cf api https://api.au-syd.bluemix.net
cf api https://api.us-east.bluemix.net
```

You can also get an overview of existing endpoints using the I[BM Cloud CLI](https://clis.ng.bluemix.net/ui/all_versions.html) with the `regions` command:

```
>> bx regions
Listing regions...

Name       Geolocation      Customer   Deployment   Domain                CF API Endpoint                   Type   
eu-de      Germany          IBM        Production   eu-de.bluemix.net     https://api.eu-de.bluemix.net     public   
au-syd     Sydney           IBM        Production   au-syd.bluemix.net    https://api.au-syd.bluemix.net    public   
us-east    US East          IBM        Production   us-east.bluemix.net   https://api.us-east.bluemix.net   public   
us-south   US South         IBM        Production   ng.bluemix.net        https://api.ng.bluemix.net        public   
eu-gb      United Kingdom   IBM        Production   eu-gb.bluemix.net     https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net     public
```

Answer (score 1):

for change region login, example:

```
bx login -a https://api.ng.bluemix.net
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but since it still tops nicely on googled results, maybe throw in the current commands ( choose one that applies for you ):

```
$ ibmcloud target --cf-api https://api.us-south.cf.cloud.ibm.com
$ ibmcloud target --cf-api https://api.us-east.cf.cloud.ibm.com
$ ibmcloud target --cf-api https://api.eu-de.cf.cloud.ibm.com
$ ibmcloud target --cf-api https://api.eu-gb.cf.cloud.ibm.com
$ ibmcloud target --cf-api https://api.au-syd.cf.cloud.ibm.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these instructions.

1. Use the below command to verify your credentials: `cf login -a https://api.example.com -u username@example.com -p Password`
2. use `cf login -a $url -u xxx@abc.com -p xxxxx` instead of `cf login -a $url` command.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the extended **cf cli** which is now **bx cli** (the BlueMix CLI). With the **bx cli** installed you simply type:
    bx regions

This will list all the available regions and api endpoints available. With that in hand now you can connect to your preferred region/api. Below is the output from the **bx regions** command:

```
bx regions
Listing Bluemix regions...

Name       Geolocation      Customer   Deployment   Domain               CF 
API Endpoint                  Type
eu-de      Germany          IBM        Production   eu-de.bluemix.net    
https://api.eu-de.bluemix.net    public
au-syd     Sydney           IBM        Production   au-syd.bluemix.net   
https://api.au-syd.bluemix.net   public
us-south   US South         IBM        Production   ng.bluemix.net       
https://api.ng.bluemix.net       public
eu-gb      United Kingdom   IBM        Production   eu-gb.bluemix.net    
https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net    public
```

You can get the **bx cli** from here https://clis.ng.bluemix.net/ui/all_versions.html.

Hope this helps.